# Difference between > and >> in Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm learning Boost-Spirit, from [*here*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html) and [*examples*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) from StackOverflow.

However, I'm not able to find the difference between `>` and `>>` *"followed by"* sequence operator ?

For Instance , the difference here :-

```
        qi::phrase_parse(startIt
        , endIt
        , par_ob > ';' // par_ob >> ';' ??
        , qi::space
        , result
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation and you will find:

> Like the Sequence, the expectation operator, a > b, parses two or
>   more operands (a, b, ... etc.), in sequence:
>
> a > b > ...
>
> However, while the plain Sequence simply returns a no-match (returns
>   false) when one of the elements fail, the expectation: > operator
>   throws an expectation_failure when the second or succeeding
>   operands (all operands except the first) fail to match.

See:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/expect.html

Comment: This answer is void of information.

I was of the opinion, that spirit is using bool to indicate success.

In which case would I use on or the other operator?